# assigning random value to 2d array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following function which generates random numbers and I have got a two dimensional array, how can I assign the values generated by the function on random location on array while it is not out of the array size?

```
int size = 10;
int randm(){
random_device seeder;
mt19937 engine(seeder());
uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 100);
return dist(engine);

}    
int** ary = new int*[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
ary[i] = new int[size];
```

Comment: [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is a good start, but have it generate a valid index instead? (I.e. in the range of `0` and `size - 1`.)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg does that has anything to do with the assigning the generated value on random location of the array?

Comment: @user2666310 It has everything to do with keeping the random location from being out of the array size, so yes. Please try to *think about* and then *apply* some of the advice that you are given.

Comment: @JasonC alright but I still don't have any idea how would I assign the values and the random number value needs to be between 0, 100. what I want is since the array will have 10 rows and 10 columns assign the generated number value on random location like 4, 4.. 2, 5 something like.

Comment: @user2666310 `array[i][j] = k` will set the the value of `array` at `[i][j]` to `k`.

Comment: @JasonC okay but how would I randomize the location? since the array has size of 10, how can I assign 5 values on random location, I guess I could use for or while loop and call the random function but, still I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

To assign your random number in a random location, you have to generate two other random numbers : one for the first index and one for the second.

For example, with your example code, you could do the following :

```
// Create a random number generator in the range [0, size-1]
random_device seeder;
mt19937 engine(seeder());
uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, size - 1);

// Assign a random value in a random place
ary[dist(engine)][dist(engine)] = randm();
```